# Get query parameter from Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, query-string

I have an issue with Firebase Dynamic Link.

I have Short URL link = *https://myappname.page.link/xyz* and I want to send some dynamic data with the link and get those data in my application.

What I found so far is using query parameter *link* so it will be like

*https://myappname.page.link/xyz?link=https://www.example.com/name=xxx&id=yyy*

I search for solution and found this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive but this get the deeplink, not query paramter link.

**Firebase Configuration** 
Short URL link : https://myappname.page.link/xyz 
Dynamic Link : https://myweb.com 
Behavior for Android : Open the deep link in your Android App

Do you have any example of how to get the *link* parameter?

I tested my link by enter *https://myappname.page.link/xyz?link=https://www.example.com/name=xxx&id=yyy* in Chrome Browser

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fetch custom parameters from Firebase Dynamic Links is to have the parameters added in the deep link. You can check [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#retrieve_referral_information_in_your_app) for more details. Parameters appended to the short link won't be passed to the deep link and can't be fetched by `pendingDynamicLinkData.link.getQueryParameter(String)`.